# air xmlhttprequest can't send GET parameters

Tags: javascript, air, xmlhttprequest

This is the code that's called on a button click and works fine

```
var console = console || 
    {log:function(msg){window.runtime.trace(msg);}};
    console.log("opening link:"+bannerurl);
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlhttp.open("GET", bannerurl,false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    document.getElementById("banner").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

output is:

> opening link:http://www.mysite.com

when I add the following line:

```
bannerurl=bannerurl+"?hi=22";
```

The output is:

```
> opening link:http://www.mysite.com?hi=22 
> Error: NETWORK_ERR:XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 
> setup1 at app:/js/result.js : 435
```

The url http://www.mysite.com?hi=22 (replaced real url with mysite as example) works perfectly fine and the code works fine in Firefox with forcecors but won't run in AIR.

rant about AIR
will answer this question later when I am allowed. The problem was that IE was set to work offline so only pages that were already cached worked but not the new ones (with different GET parameters)

Comment: It's a cross-domain issue. You need to send the allow-access-control-origin * HTTP header from your site.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but that's not it: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7eb3.html "In contrast to a browser, AIR allows content running in the application sandbox to request data from any domain."

Comment: After pulling out more hair I found out that Internet explorer was in offline mode. I almost never use IE so didn't notice this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Internet explorer was in offline mode. I almost never use IE so didn't notice this.